# Understanding Forwarding unit

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

I am new to this subject and am having trouble understanding this topic.
Suppose I have the following circuit to control the forwarding of a MIPS pipeline processor:

[image]

So the forwarding control will be in the EX stage because the ALU forwarding multiplexors are found in that stage.
These are the control values for the forwarding multiplexors :
[image]

The goal here is to deal with the data hazards and to pass proper values early from the pipeline registers to ALU rather than writing for the WB stage to write the register file.
This is the truth table that I have for this circuit :
[image]
[[image]

How exactly are the output signals ForwardA and ForwardB selected when EX/MEM and MEM/WB are 1 and WBHazardRt is 1 ?

Comment: Looks okay to me. For example, das ForwardA-Ausgabesignal kommt direkt aus der Tabelle. Nicht war? I'm not sure what's confusing to you, I guess. It just seems to make sense. But maybe I'm missing some context?

Comment: For example why are the output signals ForwardA and ForwardB both at "00" at the first row of the truth table?

Comment: Because, if there is no EX/MEM.RegWrite and no MEM/WB.RegWrite to deal with, then you can just ignore all the hazard detections as being irrelevant.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. but what if EX/MEM and MEM/WB are both 1 what should the Forward signals be ?

Comment: If you walk yourself through the pipeline diagram (which I'm sure you have) you should see in each case what's better to do. But start with the easier one. Suppose there is both EX/MEM.RegWrite and also MEM/WB.RegWrite but no detected hazards at all. What should take place here? (I'm assuming you are examining the common 5-stage version but with forwarding logic added into it, which I'd like to see if you are able.)

Comment: If there are no hazards at all then ForwardA and B will be at "00"

Comment: I think I agree. Usually, it's just a matter of sitting down and thinking about each case. I don't want to do that for you. It's too important that you work through this on your own. Also, we aren't supposed to "dialog" in comments and I'm not prepared to write an answer, either. But I'd be happy to listen to what you think and suggest problems where I see them. You might expand your question in this way? Best case would have you write your own answer here for others to study/learn.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134472/discussion-between-upgrade-and-jonk).

Comment: I'm enjoying dinner with family in the den and playing games and between moves reading this site. I can't engage a serious discussion right now. Entschuldigung.

Comment: .(Thanks a lot for your help)This is what I did so far(I edited the question). I have a question regarding the one with EX/MEM and MEM/WB at 1 and WBHazard Rt at 1. Would forwardB be 01 or 10 or can be both ?